# Magento Notification Message Issues In Admin & Front-End

Tags: magento

I have customized the new style for meagento notification messages in below path `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php`

Below Code is i have customized

```
public function getGroupedHtml()
    { 

        $types = array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
        );
       $html = '';
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) 
            {               

                foreach ( $messages as $message ) 
                {
                    $html.= '<div class="ml-alert-2-'.$type.'">';
                    $html.= '<div class="style-2-icon '.$type.'"></div>';
                    $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->htmlEscape($message->getText()) : $message->getText();
                    $html.= '<div class="style-2-close '.$type.'" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"></div>';
                    $html.= '</div>';
                }

            }
        }


        return $html;
    }
```

I have replaced the Default Magento theme in above function, The Notification Theme Works fine in Fron-end, But The Admin panel Notification Themes not applied..

So How to find the message type like (Admin message,Front-end message) in above function?

Please suggest me ?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontend and backend messages are handled by different block classes. The code you are editing is only used in the frontend of Magento. If you wish to customise the Backend messages you will need to edit/overload a different class, namely `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Messages` (which is located in `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Messages.php`).